# Uploading audio file to Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Can one upload `mp3` or `ogg` files to Azure CDN (`Cloud service` origin type)? I ask because I tried to do it directly via the portal, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you create a blob storage account and expose it on the CDN.

Then upload your files and they will be available on the Azure CDN. Use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) or [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to upload your files.

[See here for a walk through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn)

Comment: Well to be exact, I do have around 5 endpoints set up that are already serving a ton of static assets (4 with `Storage` origin type, 1 with `Cloud service`). I specifically ran into a problem when I tried to add audio files to the same location.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wouldn't expect that to be an issue. What were you using to upload?

Comment: Just added an `.mp3` and `.ogg` file. Kept it right where my images are stored. Works perfectly on `localhost`. All static folders are mapped to Azure CDN (and in case it matters, it's a Django project). How do you suppose I should go about diagnosing this?

Comment: What error did you get? Add that to your Question please.

Comment: Actually nothing: when I upload directly via the portal, it shows me an uploading notification *forever*. Also, when I peer into the anticipated CDN address the audio files ought to upload to, I see a 404 error.

Comment: That's not very helpful from the portal. I suggest you raise a support ticket. You could try build a simple app service in Visual Studio and deploy from there and check what errors come back over the wire, but it will be a bit tedious. The only other option I can think of is something on your network interfering (router, switch, firewall, policy etc).

Comment: Hey guys - let's not have a discussion in comments. Way too many details showing up here (and this is happening under an answer, not the question). @Hassan - please edit your question to contain these extra details.